# Do I need a passport for Switzerland and Iceland?

Tags: schengen, passports, switzerland, iceland, italian-citizens

I need a clarification about the necessity of having a passport while travelling in Europe (I am an Italian citizen, living in Italy). I'm going to go in Iceland but the plane will stop in Geneva (Switzerland), which will be a port of call. Do I need a passport to board the second flight or my national ID card is enough? Could I shortly visit Geneva without the passport while waiting for the second plane? 
My doubt is due to the fact Switzerland is an external member of the Schengen Area.

(Additional question: can my national driving license be used as ID card also in foreign countries?)

Comment: This journey is entirely within the Schengen border area. Switzerland is in the Schengen but not in the EEA.

Comment: Specifically about driving license: remember that driving license does not prove your citizenship, so it cannot be accepted as an ID at immigration point. Not even all hotels accept driving license and demand for a national ID or passport.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enter Switzerland on your national ID, however you are not allowed to use your driving license. As per [the website of the Swiss State State Secretariat for Migration](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/publiservice/weisungen-kreisschreiben/visa/liste1_staatsangehoerigkeit/i.html) Italian citizens can use a valid national identity card to enter Switzerland, however there's no mention of a driving license. As such you would have no issues to exit the airport to visit Geneva.

As for Iceland, according to the [Icelandic Directorate of Immigration website](https://www.utl.is/index.php/en/who-does-not-need-a-visa#I), you can enter with a *Carta d'Identità* with again no mention of a driving license.

As others mentioned in the comments, both Switzerland and Iceland are part of the Schengen area, even though neither is part of the EU. As such you might not even encounter an immigration check during the trip.